# BeforeDoubleClick on Protected Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I wrote some code that manipulates the target cell when it is double-clicked by the user.  The code works fine for most cells on the worksheet.

But the worksheet is protected (only unlocked cells are accessible), and if the user happens to double-click on one of the locked cells, the code executes as if that cell (that happened to be selected at the time of the double-click occurred) was the one double-clicked.

Can anyone think of a way to recognize that the double-click occurs on a locked cell?  Thank you.

Comment: I've tried to replicate your issue but couldn't succeed. If I enable to select locked cells, then it just works correctly and `BeforeDoubleClick` shows the correct information. If I don't enable selection of locked cells, only unlocked than Excel doesn't work correctly and I just can't select anything, that's probably not related to VBA. I'm using Excel 2013. Maybe you could share more details how exactly you experience the issue.

Comment: I think Maté misunderstands the issue. I can simulate it. The fact is that if you double click outside of the cells that can be selected, the macro runs for the cell that is still selected within the unlocked range.
I haven't found a solution though ;-)

Comment: I did some more testing but still to no avail :-(  I added `MsgBox Target.Address` in the doubleClick event to know where it is triggered from, and then disabled selection by `.EnableSelection = xlNoSelection`, but that would still give me just the unlocked cells when I clicked on a locked cell.
I tried the other events but they all are not triggered when clicking the locked part. So, sorry!

Comment: Thank you both.  Yes, Máté ... I think you may have missed my point.  I was trying to "idiot-proof" my application by imagining ways in which the user may mis-use it, and not break it. Thank you for trying!  Joost, that you also for trying ... Please see below; Joku offers an interesting and very simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar question today. After some searching I came up empty, so I devised my own solution. The basic idea is to capture the current position of the cursor on the screen and find which cell overlaps that position.

Put this in a normal code module:

```
Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (pos As POINTAPI) As Long

Type POINTAPI
    X As Long
    Y As Long
End Type
```

Then use this in your worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim pos As POINTAPI
    Dim RealTarget As Range

    'Get the cursor position
    GetCursorPos pos

    'Get the range that overlaps cursor position
    Set RealTarget = ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(pos.X, pos.Y)

    If RealTarget.Locked Then
        'Put your code for locked cells here.

        'Cancel to avoid entering the currently selected unlocked cell.
        Cancel = True
    Else
        'Put your code for unlocked cells here.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Very clever (and simple) ... thank you.  There are so many objects, methods, and functions that I have never been aware of (and now that I think about it some that I would expect ... that don't)  Much appreciated.  Will have to try and implement this!